# Почему лог journald в бинарном виде?

Tags: linux, debian, centos, centos7, redhat

Ранее dmesg сохранял лог файлы в текстовом варианте. Почему journald сохраняет в бинарном виде? Это как то связано с тем, что бинарный файл при взломе труднее подделать?

Comment: Потому что Леннарт Поттеринг так решил, когда делал systemd. Если логи повредятся, то прочитать их будет намного сложнее:) А индексировать/искать - это обычным пользователям не нужно. Они не всегда даже знают о логах как таковых. Поэтому, даже если они будут отсутствовать, ничего не поменяется. Так почему не сделать их бинарными (табличка "Сарказм").

Comment: @KoVadim а именно с systemd пошла популяризация бинарнгог варианта в Linux? Вроде часть скриптов запуска тоже перешла в бинарный вариант файлов. Хотя Linux по определению это файлы и большая часть в текстовом варианте

Comment: Как бы только в нем и используются бинарные логи. Да, всякие базы данных также используют "бинарные логи", но это не те логи

Answer (score 2):

<s>гнилые отмазки Поттеринга</s> [реклама бесподобных преимущств бинарного формата](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/journal-files/):

> - Fully indexed by all fields
> - Can store binary data, up to 2^64-1 in size
> - Seekable
> - Primarily append-based, hence robust to corruption
> - Support for in-line compression
> - Support for in-line Forward Secure Sealing

мой вольный перевод:

> - полностью индексируем по всем полям
> - может хранить бинарные данные размером до 2^64-1
> - возможен поиск
> - данные преимущественно добавляются, потому устойчив к повреждениям
> - поддержка построчного сжатия
> - поддержка построчного [forward secure sealing](https://lwn.net/Articles/512895/)